# Native language problem in mysql with tinyMCE

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I have turkish character problem in mysql database when adding content with tinymce from admin panel.

Charset is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9"" />
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the table in MySQL is also defined as having charset ISO-8859-9.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to say what your problem is, but in general you need the same character set in your HTML page (`text/html;charset`), PHP's connection to the database (`mysql_set_charset`), and MySQL's `CREATE TABLE ... DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` (if you just `CREATE TABLE` it will end up in Latin-1 which you probably don't want. Plus you would need to make sure not to use `htmlentities`-without-charset-argument on output (use `htmlspecialchars` instead).

See eg. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823844/php-mysql-and-encoding/2827677#2827677) for more detail. That's talking about using UTF-8 for the encoding, but the same applies if you substitute `ISO-8859-9` all the way through. (Although unless there's a good reason not to, you should really be using UTF-8.)

Answer (score 0):

well I had a similar problem with my turkish site.

My tables were in latin5_turkish_ci an the charset of the php page were latin5

there was no problem when I submitted the content via php to database, all characters were being saved correctly

but when I tried to submit the content via jquery post method then any turkish character was being saved correctly to database

and php iconv function solved my problem