# What encoding does Flash Builder use to send non-English data to servers?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, http, utf-8

In my site I use Unicode... I hoped when I'll connect Flash Builder to my server (using Data    -> connect to HTTP ) It will work with my API sending Russian text as UTF-8 but instead it sends `ÃÅ¾ÃÂ»ÃÂµÃÂ³ ÃÂ¯ÃÂºÃ‘Æ’Ã‘Ë†ÃÂºÃÂ¸ÃÂ½` to my API and so to DB and so on instead of my favourite UTF-8 `&#1056;&#1091;&#1089;&#1089;&#1082;&#1086;&#1077; &#1048;&#1084;&#1103; 2`... So what encoding uses flash builder and How to make Flash  Application send UTF-8 data to my server or some other readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flash application *is* sending UTF-8 to your application, but you're interpreting it as ISO-8859-1. Make sure your application keeps all data in UTF-8 all the way through and this won't be a problem. ([Outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823844/php-mysql-and-encoding/2827677#2827677) of using UTF-8 with MySQL.)

`&#1056;` isn't UTF-8, it's an HTML character reference. You *don't* want your client side to be sending you HTML-encoded content and you definitely don't want HTML-encoded content inside the database. Keep it all raw UTF-8 bytes until the moment it goes onto an HTML page (and then use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode `<` and `&` in the text, but leave non-ASCII characters alone.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is very good at keeping everything UTF-8, so the likely culprit here is PHP. I've made the mistake of not setting the proper encoding for the MySQL connection more than a couple of times, maybe that is your problem?